# Adding more views to web app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web

I'm building a admin panel using Rail, however I came across something while creating views. Let's say I want add more views on top of the completed app, I would have to go and add that menu item and it's sub views to every other view. (It's not very efficient, I know). I'm sure there is better way to go about this, I'm new to the web dev scene and I'm hoping someone can help me out here...

Comment: What is your situation? What do you need to do?

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more what you want to do? You need to add a view on every pages (example, a header) without adding this html code in every views?

Comment: Alright lets say I have a web app with 3 views (Users, Store, Settings.). So in all I have 3 html files with the appropriate names users.html, store.html, and settings.html, note that each html file has a navbar with the appropriate urls to navigate to each page. So my delima here is let's say I want to add 1 more web view called "Tables" (tables.html), how can I place those changes in the other views because those other 3 files don't reflect the new navbar. (Without having to go to each file and write those changes.)